# Looping through object to perform maths to nearest high integer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, math

I am looking to loop through an object, get a set of value(s), and then work out the difference between that value and the next whole integer.

For example, let's say I have this object:

```
const data = [
   {
      "uid": "1121212",
      "amount": {
         "money": 11.2
      },
      "sourceAmount": {
         "money": 2.2
      }
   },
   {
      "uid": "343343443",
      "amount": {
         "money": 222.30
      },
      "sourceAmount": {
         "money": 444
      }
   },
   {
      "uid": "44",
      "amount": {
         "money": 54.21
      },
      "sourceAmount": {
         "money": 32
      }
   }
]
```

If possible, I am looking to loop through this and get the value's out of the `amount.money` keys, and work out the difference between that number and the next integer. So in the above example, it would be possible to get the values `11.22` & `222.30` & `54.21` and work out the difference to `12` `223` and `55` as these are the next values. So the differences would be like: `78` & `70` and `79`. These values (I was thinking) could be pushed into an array?

I have been looking through the `map()` feature, but am struggling to form something that does what I need? I have something that looks like:

```
const difference = [];

for (let i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    var money = data.amount.money[i];
    let roundedNumber = Math.ceil(money);
    let d = function (money, roundedNumber) { return Math.abs(roundedNumber - money); }
    difference.push(d)
}
```

I think this is a bad attempt, any help on best practise would be great.

The difference array should look like: `const difference = ['78', '70', '79'];` or `const difference = ['0.78', '0.70', '0.79'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) combination could work:

```js
const data = [ { "uid": "1121212", "amount": { "money": 11.2 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 2.2 } }, { "uid": "343343443", "amount": { "money": 222.30 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 444 } }, { "uid": "44", "amount": { "money": 54.21 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 32 } } ]
const result = data.map(e => (Math.ceil(e.amount.money) - e.amount.money).toFixed(2));
console.log(result);
```

The first value is `0.80` because of `12 - 11.2`.

Please find as numbers parsed with `Number.parseFloat()`:

```js
const data = [ { "uid": "1121212", "amount": { "money": 11.2 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 2.2 } }, { "uid": "343343443", "amount": { "money": 222.30 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 444 } }, { "uid": "44", "amount": { "money": 54.21 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 32 } } ]
const result = data.map(e => Number.parseFloat((Math.ceil(e.amount.money) - e.amount.money).toFixed(2)));
console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: is there any way these strings can be moved to a number/int?

Comment: @user3180997 Yes, if you parse it to `Number` with wrapped like `Number.parseFloat( <here-comes-the-string> )`.

Comment: Thanks! Something like this? `const result = dataToFilter['feedItems'].map(e => (Number.parseFloat(Math.ceil(e.amount.minorUnits) - e.amount.minorUnits).toFixed(2)));`

Comment: Wrapping it around didn't convert them to numbers, still strings :( sorry to ask, any ideas?

Comment: @user3180997 Just updated what I meant earlier. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want integers in your `result` then the following might help. Applying `round()` on `float_val*100` is better than doing `float_val.toFixed(2)*100`, as the second method will lead to inaccurate results due to rounding errors.

```js
const data = [ { "uid": "1121212", "amount": { "money": 11 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 2.2 } }, { "uid": "343343443", "amount": { "money": 222.30 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 444 } }, { "uid": "44", "amount": { "money": 54.216 }, "sourceAmount": { "money": 32 } } ]
const result = data.map(e =>Math.round(100*(1-e.amount.money%1))%100);
console.log(result);
```

**Edit**:
Following your comment I added a further `%100` to my formula. I also changed some of the sample values to demonstrate the rounding behaviour. The first value returns 0 now and the last (changed) value of `54.216` will lead to a remainder of 78.4 which will then be rounded to 78.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the only problem with this, is if the numbers are the same, it is returning an array of the values "100". Rather then 0. This solution looks good but if they are the same, it should be 0 rather then 100, if that makes sense?